# Debugging an dotnet core application remote via ssh and fails to attach

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, .net-core, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug an dotnet core application on another machine(linux) from Visual Studio 2017

I can connect via ssh to the remote machine. I installed the debugger via the follwing command.

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v vs2017u5 -l ~/vsdbg
```

I can't attach to to dotnet process (see log). Is there anything I can try?

[image: attach]

`ProtocolException: Failed to attach to process: Unknown Error: 0x80131c08`

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.Protocol.PendingRequest`1.InvokeErrorFuncCore(Object args, ProtocolException ex)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.Protocol.PendingRequestBase.InvokeErrorFunc(Object args, ProtocolException ex)
CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , IPendingRequest , Object , ProtocolException )
System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.Protocol.DebugProtocol.HandleIncomingResponse(String msg)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.Protocol.DebugProtocol.HandleIncomingMessage(String msg)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.Protocol.DebugProtocol.ProcessMessageBody()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.Protocol.DebugProtocol.ReaderThreadProc()

1> ERROR: Failed to attach to process: Unknown Error: 0x80131c08
 1> WARNING: Debug adapter is still running after receiving DisconnectResponse, terminating.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Kingpin did you manage to solve this?